# How to use comments to trigger rebuilds of Bitbucket pull-requests on Jenkins multi-branch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I have successfully configured a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline to build my project which is hosted on Bitbucket. I have separate pipeline requirements for the "develop" and "release" branches, and for merge requests. These are now working correctly (except for a surplus "PR-***" job whenever a Bitbucket PR is triggered).

My remaining issue is:
In old-style Jenkins I used Bitbucket Pull Request plugin, which had a feature "Comment phrase to trigger build". So in the event of a flaky unit test etc I could issue the trigger phrase as a comment in the pull request, and it would be rebuilt.

How can I achieve this behaviour on a multi-branch pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the [Pull Request Notifier](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/pull-request-notifier-for-bitbucket) plugin for Bitbucket to trigger my Bitbucket Multibranch Pipeline builds in Jenkins.  Using the GUI configuration tools, you can configure the Pull Request Notifier plugin to trigger a build on any arbitrary PR action, including adding comments.

However, you don't really need to use comments to trigger builds - there is a build trigger button in the PR view in Bitbucket, and you can also use the "Build Now" button in Jenkins to trigger a PR build.  Both of these seem a little bit easier to me than a magic comment.